# How to create a new Organization in MixPanel

Tags: mixpanel

I am logged in MixPanel in one client's organization, with my personal professional email.
I want to create another one, with the same email, but I can't find anywhere how to do so, any clue ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the official way, but this is what I did and it worked:

1. Sign out from Mixpanel in your web browser
2. Register a new account using another email address
3. Create your new organization during account setup
4. Add yourself as a user to the newly added organization (use your primary email address)

If you are using Gmail, you can use email alias in step 2 - if your email is your_name@gmail.com, use your_name+whatever@gmail.com. Any message sent to the alias will go to your inbox.

When you log in to Mixpanel using your primary email address again, you will notice that you have access to both the old and the new organization.